Boundary value problem with extra term
One of questions of preparation to my exam is this one:

$$
\begin{cases}
k u_{xx} + r = u_t & 0 < x < 1, \quad t > 0 \\
u(0, t) = 1, \quad u(1, t) = 1, \quad & t > 0, \\
u(x, 0) = -\frac{r}{2k}x^2+\frac{r}{2k}x, & 0 < x < 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Can someone help me? I don't know what change with this additional ${}+r$. I know how to do the simple problem without ${}+r$.

Hint. Make the substitution $u(x,t)=v(x,t)-\frac{r}{2k}(x^2-x)+1$.

Thank you man, when i did this substitution i came to general case with f(x)=1
